# Why does TypeError occur in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, frontend

```
const FindEmail = () => {
const {userEmail, setUserEmail} = useState('');

    const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
        setUserEmail(e.target.value);
    }; 
    return (
      <Input className="inputEmail" value={userEmail} onChange={onChangeEmail}>
      );
    };
```

TypeError: setUserEmail is not a function when data is entered into input from these codes
How can I solve the problem?
*Input starts with a capital letter because i am using reactstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook returns a tuple and not an object:

```
const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace curly brackets with square brackets when declaring userEmail state:

```
const FindEmail = () => {
const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');

    const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
        setUserEmail(e.target.value);
    }; 
    return (
      <Input className="inputEmail" value={userEmail} onChange={onChangeEmail}>
    );
};
```